# События и делегаты

Tags: winforms, c#

Здравствуйте, есть некоторое непонимание с такой вещью как события. Просто в основном писал только консольные приложения. В общем, задача простая: по нажатию `button` в `panel` должен появляться какой-нибудь рисунок. Мне надо в методе `button_click` как-то породить ещё какое-нибудь событие для рисования в `panel`. Пытался просто сразу напрямую писать:
`button1.Click = new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint)`, но компилятор ругается на делегат `PaintEventHandler`, требует `EventHandler`.
Заранее спасибо. И вообще был бы крайне признателен, если кто-нибудь сказал сайт, на котором есть куча примеров работы с различными компонентами и как их связывать.

Answer (score 2):

> Событие Paint вызывается при перерисовке элемента управления.

Создаем обработчик событий

```
private void SomePaintEventHandler(object sender, PaintEventArgs args)
{
    // В качестве примера
    args.Graphics.DrawString("Text", new Font ("Tahoma", 12), new SolidBrush (Color.Green), 200, 200);
}
```

Делегируем событие

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.SomePaintEventHandler);
```

Инициируем перерисовку контрола

```
this.Invalidate();
```

Почитать по теме: [обработка и вызов событий](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/edzehd2t.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MSDN: [PaintEventHandler - делегат](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.painteventhandler.aspx).

Comment: у меня одного MSDN не работает?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows приложения - WinForms](http://simple-cs.ru/win-app.aspx) - очень хороший сайт для начинающих, надеюсь, найдёте для себя много полезного.